# Double releasing when it shouldn't be happening

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am really puzzled by this. I believe I am managing memory the correct way but executing the code suggests that I am double releasing the object. Here is the code and then I'll explain what is happening.

```
@protocol SomeDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (id)initWithCols:(NSUInteger)Cols Rows:(NSUInteger)Rows;
@end


@interface SomeObject : NSObject <SomeDelegate> {
}
- (id)initWithCols:(NSUInteger)Cols Rows:(NSUInteger)Rows;
@end


@interface Layout : UIView {
  id<SomeDelegate> someDelegate;
}
@property(retain) id<SomeDelegate> someDelegate;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect Cols:(NSUInteger)Cols Rows:(NSUInteger)Rows;
@end


@implementation Layout
@synthesize someDelegate;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect Cols:(NSUInteger)Cols Rows:(NSUInteger)Rows {

  if(self = [super initWithFrame:aRect]) {
    cols = Cols; 
    rows = Rows;
    id<SomeDelegate> delegate = [[SomeObject alloc] initWithCols:cols Rows:rows];
    [self setSomeDelegate:delegate];
    //[delegate release];
  }
  return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [someDelegate release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Now when I uncomment out the "//[delegate release];" line in the constructor of the Layout class, then I get a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error and the application crashes when it attempts to dealloc. I have traced the crash to the release of the someDelegate object in the dealloc method of Layout class. If I leave it commented then the application works fine.

Can someone please explain why this is happening as it appears to be going against everything I have read about memory management in Objective-C.

Just a note that the code example actually works, however my code doesn't which follows the example. Could there be something inside of my actual SomeObject that is causing an autorelease?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you rename the "delegate" variable to something else? I know it shouldn't matter, but I remember reading something in the cocoa-dev mailing lists along the same lines; strange behaviour with certain variable names. UIView has its own delegate, I wonder if it has something to do with that.

Comment: Good thinking, but unfortunately I tried renaming it to delegated and it still has the releasing issue.

Comment: Just a note, the code snippet actually works so I am thinking that there is something inside my SomeObject (the full code and not the snippet) that is causing it to autorelease. Can an object autorelease itself without have been told to?

Comment: Many methods return autoreleased objects, NSString's +stringWith... and -stringBy... methods return autoreleased objects. The code you posted definitely goes by Cocoa Memory Management rules so just keep an eye out for rogue "release" and "autorelease" methods in your code, and make sure you're retaining everything that is not explicitly allocated by your own code. If it still isn't working, maybe file a bug.

Comment: The problem was a MutableArray deep in a subclass that was created through a factory (autoreleased) but I was also releasing too. THe Zombie thing helped a little in that it told me an array was the culprit but not much else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, go back and reread the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) just to make sure you are not missing anything obvious in your use of delegate elsewhere.

Next, turn on NSZombieEnabled (in your executable settings, Arguments panel, add an environment variable NSZombieEnabled set to YES).

Then add a dealloc method to your delagate if it does not have one already (make sure you call [super dealloc]!) and put a break point on there - that will tell you when your delagate is deallocated which will tell you when it is being released.

Alternatively, add trivial release/autorelease methods to your delegate class which do nothing but call through, and then breakpoint them and that will tell you exactly when it is being released.

Three final comments: in the standard naming convention for Objective C/Cocoa, you should have lowercase parameter fields, ie it should be:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect cols:(NSUInteger)Cols rows:(NSUInteger)Rows;
```

When your ivar and property are named identically, it is very easy to accidently use the wrong one, so I recommend using a different ivar name and property name to avoid confusion, either use an _ prefix like Apple, or some other prefix to avoid confusion with Apple as well:

```
  id<SomeDelegate> _someDelegate;

@synthesize someDelegate = _someDelegate;
```

And Apple recomends against using setters/getters in init/dealloc, so your init code should be:

```
_someDelegate = [[SomeObject alloc] initWithCols:cols Rows:rows];
```

Comment: For those looking on how to enable NSZombie see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode

Answer (score 2):

As alluded to in the comments, the problem does not appear to be in the code posted.

I could ask for more information, but I'm firmly in the teach a man to fish camp....

A crash in -release will often be misleading in that various optimizations -- tail call optimizations, generally -- will make it look like the crash happened a frame or two above the actual call that crashed.   When the crash happens, there isn't enough info on the stack to really identify the culprit.

Whenever you suspect you have any kind of a crash in -release or -dealloc, immediately turn on Zombies.  This can be done through Instruments or via an environment variable or by calling a function in the Foundation very early in your program's execution.

Search for "Zombies" or "NSZombie" in the documentation included with the development environment (that'd be more of the "teach a man to fish" thing).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a MutableArray deep in a subclass that was created through a factory (autoreleased) but I was also releasing too. Unfortunately the crash wouldn't indicate which inherited dealloc was causing the crash and just stop on the first overridden dealloc.

The Zombie thing helped a little in that it told me an array was the culprit but not much else. I think there is more to NSZombie and requires more experience to take full advantage of it.