# Objective-c error "-[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4593540"

Tags: objective-c, cordova

Im using phonegap and currently I have a webapp with php and javascript / html running inside of an iframe. It worked for a while but now it crashes with this error when I load the page

```
-[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4593540
```

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a retain count problem. From another Stack Overflow answer:

> First, go back and reread the [memory
>   management rules](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) just to make sure
>   you are not missing anything obvious
>
> Next, turn on NSZombieEnabled (in your
>   executable settings, Arguments panel,
>   add an environment variable
>   NSZombieEnabled set to YES).

[Double releasing when it shouldn't be happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060912/double-releasing-when-it-shouldnt-be-happening/1061641#1061641)

Here's a helpful [post about NSZombieEnabled](http://cocoa-nut.de/?p=16)

Answer (score 0):

The static analyzer might find the issue (Build menu >> **Build and Analyze**).

Also, enable "**Stop on Objective-C Exceptions**" under the Run menu (**activate breakpoints** first). Then run the app and it will stop when it hits the exception. Then you can use the debugger to find the line where the error occurred.